# Can I store a fresh turkey in my garage for a few days?

Tags: food-safety, turkey

I have a 25 lb. fresh turkey and would like to store it in my garage if possible. It's 43F during the day, and 33F at night - will it be safe to do that?

Comment: 43F, 6C? Is that temperature the forecast? It will be hotter if your garage gets sun on/into it. Since it's in the danger zone (even though it's just a bit,) the answer is pretty much no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat)

Comment: @TFD : 33-43°F is room temperature?  I'm hoping you wear a sweater.

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't vote to close because I feel there's an implicit question here: if that doesn't work, what *can* I do? So simply closing as duplicate and saying "nope no good" seems less helpful than we could be.

Comment: @Joe First bold paragraph of linked answer! Is the linked answer wrong?

Comment: @TFD : if it hasn't been done yet, and the person is asking how to do it safely, than that question has nothing to do with this one.

Comment: @Joe just being pedantic, but the OP does not use the word "how". A more general question is required here, this one is going to be wasted

Comment: @TFD : the correct answer is 'yes, if you chill it'.  Not 'you should throw it away'.

Answer (score 6):

As setek said in the comments, 43F is too warm. Anything above 40F and you only have a couple hours before it's unsafe (has the potential to make people sick, even if unlikely). And your garage is attached to a house that's well over 40F, so it'll probably be well above 43F in there.

So you really need to keep it chilled. If you don't have space in your fridge, you might be able to make do with an ice chest; if it's really at most 43F, the ice will last a long time.

Comment: My neighbors do this every year, w/ the ice chest filled w/ brine & ice, so there's plenty of thermal mass.